# Calling SAP Function Module through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function-module

Is it possible to call a function module in SAP through a stored procedure in SQL Server that is linked to the SAP SQL Server?

I know its not the right way to do things and I should do this using the SAP application layer, but I am not concerned about this at this particular moment.

Comment: Not really sure if this is possible. I only found some documentation about connection and data selection between MS-SQL Server and SAP BW. What exactly do you want to do? Call a FM in an ERP or BW-System? I think we need more information.

Comment: @Sasku Call a FM in ERP and insert the output of that FM call into a table in a separate sql server.

Comment: I suppose the only way to call an FM is SAP .Net Connector

Comment: @Suncatcher do you mean in SSIS packages?

Comment: no, it is a [separate package](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/msnet.html) with separate installer which has nothing to do with SSIS